# Toggle in pure CSS, with a child element

Tags: css, focus, css-selectors, toggle

I am trying to do a toggle in pure CSS using :focus pseudo-selector.

My problem is I try to do the focus on parent element and change both child elements and adjacent selector.

```
<p class="collapser" tabindex="0">FILTERS
<span class="dblArrow right">
    <i class="icon icon-double-chevron-right" tabindex="0">>></i>
    <i class="icon icon-double-chevron-left" tabindex="0"><<</i>
</span>
</p>
<ul class="filters">.....
```

On the click on collapser (or the arrows in `<i>`), I want to display the `<ul>` or hide it, and changing the arrows.

You can view a demo of what I achieved until now : http://jsfiddle.net/TmzC7/9/
It has drawbacks : when you click anywhere outside the collapser the filters are hidden. To hide the filters, you have to click on the arrows.

If there is a solution so that either the arrows or the whole collapser (better) can handle the toggle and switch arrows, it would be great, but I reckon you have to use JavaScript for this...

I tried to do things like :

```
.collapser:focus  .icon-double-chevron-right:focus + .icon-double-chevron-left {
   opacity:1;
   text-indent:0;
}
```

to detect click on the arrows, but it did not work. I assume focus does not bubble.

Is there a trick (like playing on tabindex or something) to achieve this without JavaScript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

using the examples here http://ghinda.net/css-toggle-switches/

i was able to do this http://jsfiddle.net/DbXQs/

it seems like the catch is to use the `:checked` selector.

hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `:target` selector, like this :

```css
.icon-double-chevron-right,
.icon-double-chevron-left,
.filters {
    padding: 10px;
    margin: 0;
    list-style: none;
    display:block;
    border: 1px solid #000;
}

.filters,
.icon-double-chevron-left,
.icon-double-chevron-right:target {
     display: none;
}

.icon-double-chevron-right:target + .icon-double-chevron-left,
.icon-double-chevron-right:target ~ .filters {
    display:block;
}

a { 
    color: #333;
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
  <div>
    <a href="#hide" class="icon icon-double-chevron-right" id="hide">&gt;&gt;</a>
    <a href="#show" class="icon icon-double-chevron-left" id="show">&lt;&lt;</a>
    <ul id="drop"  class="filters">
        <li>
          <a href="#">FILTER 1</a>           
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="#">FILTER 2</a>            
        </li> 
    </ul>
</div>
```

(see also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/wx1yu9vd/))